# ExternalInterface.call() not getting return value

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have a Javascript function that returns the innerHTML of a div.  I am attempting to call this function from Actionscript and store the return value.   I know that the Javascript function is being called because there is an alert that displays the return data, The data that is returned to Actionscript, however, is null.  I am not sure what is causing this.  Here is a code example of what I am attempting to do:

```
Javascript:
function JSFunc () {
     var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
     alert(x.innerHTML);
     return x.innerHTML;
}

Actionscript:
import flash.external.*;
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
     var retData:Object = ExternalInterface.call("JSFunc");
     if(retData != null) {
          textField.text = retData.toString();
     } else {
          textField.text = "Returned Null";
     }
} else {
     textField.text = "External Interface not available";
}
```

Like I said earlier, the alert shows up with the contents of the div but the text in the textfield is always "Returned Null", meaning that the ExternalInterface is available.  I should add that I can only test this in IE7 and IE8.  Any advice on what to do would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem that I have been having has to do the object tag that I was using to embed the flash movie. I was using a tag that followed this example http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp, I changed it to match this example: http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_4150 and then I made sure that I added id to the object and everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

[This is a working sample](http://osmanu.com/flex/EITest/EITest.html) based on the code you provided. You can right click it to view the source. I suspect the problem lies in the HTML for 'myDiv' or when you are making the actionscript call.

Comment: Thank you for showing that the code itself is not the problem, I am thinking that the issue might be with the object tag that I used to embed the movie in IE. Also how to do I see the javascript and the div that you used?

Comment: nm, I found the javascript and div.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `as String` to the call:

```
textField.text = ExternalInterface.call("JSFunc") as String;
```

Comment: Gave typecasting a shot but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed you got a typo in your code  =>   textField != textfield

Comment: Sorry for the mistake the code is an example not what I am actually using.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with that code, unless some other part of your code is messing with up with the textfield content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the object back from your external interface call without casting it first, and take a look at it in the debugger. If it is not a string, trying to cast it to a string will result in null. This should be a string, but it doesn't hurt to see what you are actually getting back before you try to work with it.

Comment: The object is null, is what the debugger is telling me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is that from javascript you are returning a string, the innerHTML property of your myDiv element.  In actionscript you have datatyped the variable that the ExternalInterface call returns to as an Object, but it is a String.  Maybe you have already caught this, but I can't tell as you haven't amended your code.

```
//The following is an Object
var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");

/*
You are returning the innerHTML property of x, a string, but on the
flash end your expecting an object in your actionscript.
*/
return x.innerHTML;

//The following seems incorrect to me.
var retData:Object = ExternalInterface.call("JSFunc");

//Should be
var retData:String = ExternalInterface.call("JSFunc");
```

Hope this was helpful, take care.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the import statement

```
import flash.external.*;
```