# ExternalInterface.call not returning object in IE

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm making the following call in actionscript

```
var data:Object = ExternalInterface.call("getData");
trace("data is", data);  // data is null in IE7-9, but works in FF
```

To the following function in javascript

```
function getData() {
    var data = {example : "data"};
    console.log("data", data); //displays as expected in the console
    return data;
}
```

Using swfObject2 for the embed with the following code (copied this from my existing code and cleaned it up a bit, though there will be a few undefined variables below):

```
var This                = this,
    divId               = "myDiv",
    widgetData          = serviceData.flashvars,
    swfURL              = "http://mysite.com/my.swf",
    flashvars           = widgetData,  //external object, not used in this case
    params              = {
        movie: serviceData.swfURL,
        pluginspage: "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer",
        align: "middle",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        quality: "high",
        allowFullScreen: "true",
        wmode: "transparent",
        bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
        menu: "false"
    },
    expressInstallURL   = "http://mysite.com/expressInstall2.swf?2",
    attributes          = {id : divId + "_mySWF", name: divId + "_mySWF"},
    callback            = function (e) {
        console.log("player loaded");
    };
flashVideoPlayer = swfobject.embedSWF(swfURL, divId, widgetData.width, widgetData.height, "10", expressInstallURL, flashvars, params, attributes, callback);
```

and all the usuals are included in the html, like ids, allowscriptaccess, and I'm not inside a form tag.  There are no initialization issues that I know of because the javascript is displaying the data inside getData, so that function has to exist before it is called, etc. The issue seems to be with javascript returning objects to flash.

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701200/externalinterface-call-not-getting-return-value?rq=1) didn't seem to help either, but my case is a bit different because I'm using swfObject.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: +1 for the Cute graviatar ..!

Comment: I tried the same thing in IE-7 Win browser and it seemed to be working

Comment: The only place it can break is if IE is not recognising `console` in `console.log("data", data);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that one line of AS3 code you provided is all you got, but if so you could try the following:

```
private function sendToJS(e:MouseEvent):void {  
    if(ExternalInterface.available) {  
        ExternalInterface.call("fromAS", doSomethingHere);  
    }  
}
```

which I used myself once.